# For-Loop Stopping after 1 Iteration

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

For this part of my assignment I need to do the following:

> Create a function that returns a sorted list of string type keys and integer type values. Inside the function, declare a new sorted list that has the same structure as the function’s return type. Then, using a nested for loop for populating the sorted list, go through the product list and year list such that the product and year is concatenated together to create a key, and the corresponding demand value from the demand table array is retrieved as the value for this key to be entered to the sorted list.

I've written the following code to do that, however it throws "'System.ArgumentException' in System.dll" after 1 iteration. The test MessageBox will only display "ModelX 2013 205" and then the error will be thrown.

```
    Public Function GetProductDemand() As SortedList(Of String, Integer)
    Dim prodDemand As New SortedList(Of String, Integer)

    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For Each product In products
        For Each yr In years
            Dim key As String
            key = product & " " & yr
            For i As Integer = 0 To 4
                prodDemand.Add(key, demand(count, i)) 'stops here after 1 iteration
                MessageBox.Show(key & " " & prodDemand(key)) 'test to display results
            Next
        Next
        count += 1
    Next
    Return prodDemand
End Function
```

Any reason why this is happening? Here's the rest of the relevant code:

```
    Dim products As List(Of String)
Dim years As List(Of String)
Dim demandList As SortedList(Of String, Integer)
Dim demand As Integer(,)

Private Sub frmDemand_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    products = GetProducts()
    years = GetYears()
    demand = GetDemand()
    demandList = GetProductDemand()
End Sub

Private Function GetDemand() As Integer(,)
    Return {
            {205, 220, 245, 230},
            {160, 174, 152, 144},
            {480, 424, 396, 456}
           }
End Function

Public Function GetProducts() As List(Of String)
    Dim prods As New List(Of String)
    prods.Add("ModelX")
    prods.Add("ModelY")
    prods.Add("ModelZ")
    Return prods
End Function

Public Function GetYears() As List(Of String)
    Dim yr As New List(Of String)
    yr.Add("2013")
    yr.Add("2014")
    yr.Add("2015")
    yr.Add("2016")
    Return yr
End Function
```

Comment: `prodDemand.Add(key, demand(count, i))` can we see prodDemand and demand? I'm thinking you are calling it/them with improper arguments on the second iteration of your loop.

Comment: @blaze_125: You're correct -- `SortedList` is basically a dictionary, and adding the same key more than once would throw an error (duplicate keys).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I read the problem statement closer**. I don't think you need the inner-most for loop. The answer here is to base the indices off of the lists:

```
Public Function GetProductDemand() As SortedList(Of String, Integer)
    Dim prodDemand As New SortedList(Of String, Integer)
    For i = 0 To products.Length - 1
        For j As Integer = 0 To years.Length - 1
            Dim key As String = String.Format("{0} {1}", products(i), years(j))
            prodDemand.Add(key, demand(i, j))
            MessageBox.Show(key & " " & prodDemand(key)) 'test to display results
        Next
    Next
    Return prodDemand
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I made the change, but the same thing is still happening.

Comment: Ah I see. The question I'm trying to solve is in the beginning of the post. Perhaps you can suggest a better way of doing it? The way the question is worded is kinda confusing.

Comment: @TheGamingGrunts: After reading the question closer, I don't think you need the `For i As Integer = 0 To 4` loop at all. I will update my answer.

Comment: @TheGamingGrunts: Answer is updated. I know this is homework, so please don't just copy and paste this without fulling understanding it.

Comment: That's the plan. I see where I went wrong and will make the appropriate changes. I appreciate the help!

Comment: For reference... now that I have your code running and I see your error message... There is an important part of the error message you did not read or disregarded. _Additional information: An entry with the same key already exists._

Comment: That's odd... never said that in my console. The only thing it printed was "'System.ArgumentException' in System.dll". Is there a setting or something that I need to change?

Comment: @TheGamingGrunts: you saw that in the "Output" window. As you get more and more into development, logging constructs and making good use of `try/catch/[finally]` will be invaluable. Using breakpoints and debugging within the IDE would have greatly helped you self-diagnose the original exception.